# Exterior algebra as quotient algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

This is my first time posting so I apologise for the stupid question. I am trying to understand the idea of exterior algebra as a quotient algebra. Let $T(V)$ be the tensor algebra of a vector space $V$. The exterior algebra is defined as

\begin{equation}
\Lambda(V)=T(V)/I,
\end{equation}
where $I$ is the two-sided ideal generated by elements of the form $v\otimes v$ with $v\in V$. This means the ideal is the set of elements
\begin{equation}
I=\left\{\sum_i r_i\otimes v\otimes v\otimes s_i\bigg|v\in V,r_i,s_i\in T(V) \right\}.
\end{equation}
My understand of taking the quotient is that elements of the ideal should be identified as the additive identity of the algebra, $0_R$, under projection.

My question is as follows. Suppose we have the element
\begin{equation}
a\otimes b \otimes c\in V.
\end{equation}
Now I add on the following element in the ideal $a\otimes (-b+2a)\otimes (-b+2a)\in I$ -- this is in the ideal because it is of the form $a\otimes v\otimes v$. Adding an element from the ideal should mean I remain in the same equivalence class, so
\begin{equation}
a\otimes b \otimes c\sim a\otimes b\otimes c+a\otimes (-b+2a)\otimes(-b+2a)=2a\otimes2a\otimes (c-b+2a).
\end{equation}
The term on the right is in the form of an ideal. From this, I conclude that $a\otimes b\otimes c$ is also in the ideal! This is blatantly wrong. It appears as if I can always add elements of the ideal to an element in $T(V)$ that is not in the ideal to obtain one that *is* in the ideal.

Where did I go wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's not how addition of tensors works. $x\otimes y +z\otimes w \neq (x+z)\otimes (y+w)$ in general.

Comment: Oh, of course. Thank you! Can't believe I missed that!